# Performnce overhead Session Vs GUID from Meta table approcah. Yii app instances using dynamic config files created at runtime

Tags: php, mysql, apache, yii, multiple-instances

In my yii application I am creating the app by passing config files and db parameters dynamically at runtime based on the users input. My app can have thousands of users and thus thousands of instances with separate db connections of same code base. To achieve that I have separate config files for each user.

> My question:
>
> - Should I use session variable or a GUID value from meta table to map the config file path (currently using session) ?
> - Is there any possible limitation imposed by Yii, PHP or Apache on    numbers of instances of same yii app created this way concurrently? What re performance overhead